# How to pass variable from javascript to python without ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I have a get method in javascript where i download some data from a website. I load the data into a variable and I want to send the variable to python. How can I achieve this without using ajax? I have managed to pass the variable to python by using ajax post, but the problem is that I cannot render a template back in the python method. Moreover, I don't want to render the template from inside the javascript file, because the variables for the render depend upon some if else statements from python.

Answer (score 0):

Use form submit... And put action and method in th form tag